# Andorid: How do I align all the items in Relative Layout to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have put a linear layout inside a relative layout and I am trying to align the parent relative layout to the bottom of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fruits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fruits"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Message: " />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Im basically trying to center a Text and there is a Text and Edit Text underneath it and align them all to the bottom of the screen

```
            Fruits
Message: ___________________________
```

Comment: would you draw a picture to make it clear where you want things to be !?

Comment: I want this entire thing to be at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Change This:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
```

to This:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` check running the solution below in your project.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fruits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fruits"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Message: " />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think that attribute is for children of RelativeLayout, not the layout itself

Comment: for that attribute to work it should have relative layout as its parent too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
 **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">      
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" // add this to you layout
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! You have to change the Parent RelativeLayout's height **from wrap_content to match_parent**. So that it will take whole layout's height and it will append to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

set layout_above property to fruits TextView to bottom LinearLayout
Try this

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fruits"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fruits"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Message: " />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```